# PHP exec command is not returning full data from Python script

Tags: php, python, ssh, centos, exec

I am connecting to a server through PHP SSH and then using exec to run a python program on that server.

If I connect to that server through putty and execute the same command through command line, I get result like:

> Evaluating....
>
> Connecting....
>
> Retrieving data....
>
> 1) Statement 1
>
> 2) Statement 2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> N) Statement N

Python program is written by somebody else...

When I connect through SSH php, I can execute `$ssh->exec("ls")` and get the full results as proper as on server command line. But when I try `$ssh->exec("python myscript.py -s statement 0 0 0");` I couldn't  get the full results but I get a random line as an ouput.

In general, if somebody had experienced the same issue and solved, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What random lines ? Can you show example ?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot show the output. But consider having 
23) statement 23
as an output. But you were supposed to have ouput like in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's caused by buffering of the output. Try adding the `-u` option to your Python command - this forces stdout, stdin and stderr to be unbuffered.

Comment: Where in this line?
 $ssh->exec("python myscript.py -s statement 0 0 0");

Comment: One more thing I want to ask is:
If I achieve the output by your method, what is the way to proper architecture the output? Like json or xml?

Comment: Add `-u` after `python`: `$ssh->exec("python -u myscript.py -s statement 0 0 0")`

Comment: Proper architecture? It's hard to say without any details. Either has its place, but if the code is already written, I'd just use that.